# What are the original titles of books I-VI of the Lord of the Rings?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

I read that Tolkien didn't want to make the Lord of the Rings three books, and that the only

> "natural divisions are the 'books' I-VI (which originally had titles)"

What are those titles?

Answer (score 27):

I just found this in *the Letters of JRR Tolkien*, letter 137:

1. The Ring sets out
2. The Ring goes south
3. The Treason of Isengard
4. The Ring goes East
5. The War of the Ring
6. The End of the Third Age

Comment: Also in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings#Publication_history)

Comment: +1; this is correct but it should be added that the titles were just suggestions to the publisher and were never formally agreed for use; the original publication was without titles.

Comment: I have a 7 volume "Millennium" edition box set (see http://www.mytolkienbooks.com/books-by-tolkien/middle-earth-related/lord-of-the-rings/complete-sets/the-lord-of-the-rings-millennium-edition/) that uses these titles for volumes 1-6 plus the appendices. The top of the spines of the books spells out T O L K I E N

Comment: I gotta say, those are droll titles. I'm glad he just went with books I-VI

Comment: I have the same set as Gerry and I have to say it makes a much more natural division.

Comment: @TheFallen I think 3 & 5 are fine titles, but 1, 2, and 4 are definitely unsuitable for publication. 6 is not very attention grabbing for those who aren't intimately familiar with the principles behind Tolkien's ages.

Answer (score 15):

Footnote 1 of the "Note on the Text" in the 1987 edition (and later editions?) of *The Fellowship of the Ring*:

> Tolkien's titles for the six books were not used.  A contents listing with the manuscript of *The Lord of the Rings* at Marquette University gives them as follows: Volume I, "The First Journey" and "The Journey of the Nine Companions"; Volume II, "The Treason of Isengard" and "The Journey of the Ringbearers"; Volume III, "The War of the Ring" and "The End of the Third Age."  A variant set of titles can be found in *Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien*, p. 167.